# I want to show current user profile but this error happened RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#53bd6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I want to show current user profile but I got these errors  [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odQp9.png)..[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX6oV.png)..[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLUtO.png)...[error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2CHm.png)
This is my firebase database [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi7CB.png)

Here is my code

```
body: Expanded(
  child: Container(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("user3")
          .where("id", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Loading please wait........");
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["name"]);
            });
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use (& don't) `Expanded` directly on `body:`

You can use it as a child of Column or Row, or this case you can wrap the ListView.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("user3")
          .where("id", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Loading please wait........");
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["name"]);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Same error happened. I also replace my code to this code but the error is same. I also try to wrap expanded widget to Coloumn widget but the error is same

Comment: replace the snippet with current code, then try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: I also try Flutter clean

Comment: is it the main widget using on home?

Comment: Yes it is the main widget

Comment: It is strange to me you still get layout issue with current snippet, can you test on different device